# How to configure an Ultra Sonic Sensor in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, configuration, hardware

I would like to Configure an ultrasonic sensor for triggering purpose in matlab.
How to configure the ultrasonic sensor for triggering Video capturing device ?

Comment: could u plz tell me what details u need to know more abt?

Comment: this is raw data so u can just give me an example of some particular specification.

Comment: i would like to trigger an video capturing device.

Comment: Then it depends on the video capture device

Comment: The device is 160*240 frame size.and windows adaptor winvideo.But i tried triggerinfo command to get the hardware info.but it says not valid function?whats with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to configure & access your device via the data acquisition toolbox.